# Is there a way for R to get rolling mean when each group has different number of values?

Tags: r, time-series, mean, summarize, mutate

I have a dataset with 2 groupings and I also want to group by month. There are 1 to 8 observations each month. I want a column with the rolling mean of say last 3 months. So if there are 2 obs this month, 3 last month, and then 1, I want the mean of the last 6 rows.

I tried using zoo, summarise, mutate with slide_dbl, always running into issues getting the n() of each group correct.

My data:

```
 REGION   TYPE                DATE RESULT
1 3226H5 Type A 2021-01-04 10:03:00   0.71
2 3226H5 Type A 2021-01-04 10:14:39   1.47
3 3226H5 Type A 2021-01-04 10:21:23   1.28
4 3226H5 Type A 2021-01-07 09:20:00   0.90
5 3226H5 Type A 2021-02-01 10:00:00   1.39
6 3226H5 Type A 2021-02-01 10:10:00   1.42

library(slider)
library(lubridate)
my_data <- structure(list(REGION = c("3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", 
"3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", 
"3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", 
"3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", 
"3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", 
"3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", 
"3226H5", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", 
"3285", "3285", "3285"), TYPE = c("Type A", "Type A", "Type A", 
"Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", 
"Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", 
"Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", 
"Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", 
"Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", 
"Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", 
"Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B"), DATE = structure(c(1609754580, 
1609755279, 1609755683, 1610011200, 1612173600, 1612174200, 1612174800, 
1612432800, 1614593100, 1614594000, 1614594600, 1614851400, 1617617409, 
1617618215, 1617618894, 1617875485, 1620040008, 1620041400, 1620042300, 
1620295200, 1609754580, 1609755279, 1609755683, 1610011200, 1612173600, 
1612174200, 1612174800, 1612432800, 1614593100, 1614594000, 1614594600, 
1614851400, 1617617409, 1617618215, 1617618894, 1617875485, 1620040008, 
1620041400, 1620042300, 1620295200, 1609748700, 1609758900, 1612169112, 
1612177800, 1614588900, 1614599100, 1617612277, 1617622409, 1620034319, 
1620042163), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    RESULT = c(0.71, 1.47, 1.28, 0.9, 1.39, 1.42, 1.54, 0.37, 
    2.94, 2.25, 2.01, 0.52, 10.5, 1.02, 1.16, 0.62, 58.67, 0.75, 
    0.94, 2.72, 0.012, 0.004, 0.005, 0.014, 0.014, 0.005, 0.006, 
    0.009, 0.013, 0.007, 0.006, 0.015, 0.022, 0.004, 0.004, 0.009, 
    0.021, 0.005, 0.005, 0.011, 0.012, 0.012, 0.01, 0.012, 0.019, 
    0.011, 0.013, 0.012, 0.016, 0.014)), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = "data.frame")
```

My solution:

```
grouped_roll <- my_data %>%
  
  add_count(REGION, TYPE, DATE, name = "new_cases") %>%

  arrange(REGION, TYPE, DATE) %>%   
  
  group_by(REGION, TYPE)    %>%        
    
  mutate( 
     MONTHLY = floor_date(DATE, "month"),
    rolling_mean = slide_index_dbl(RESULT,
      .i = MONTHLY,      # index on date 
      .f = mean,                      
      .after = months(6)),             
    rolling_sd = slide_index_dbl(
      RESULT,
      .i = MONTHLY,
      .f = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
      .after = months(6)
    )
  )

view(grouped_roll)

grouped_roll <- grouped_roll %>%
  group_by(REGION, TYPE, MONTHLY) %>%
  slice(seq_len(1))
grouped_roll

Groups:   REGION, TYPE, MONTHLY [15]
   REGION TYPE   DATE                RESULT new_cases MONTHLY             rolling_mean rolling_sd
   <chr>  <chr>  <dttm>               <dbl>     <int> <dttm>                     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 3226H5 Type A 2021-01-04 10:03:00  0.71          1 2021-01-01 00:00:00      4.66      12.9    
 2 3226H5 Type A 2021-02-01 10:00:00  1.39          1 2021-02-01 00:00:00      5.55      14.4    
 3 3226H5 Type A 2021-03-01 10:05:00  2.94          1 2021-03-01 00:00:00      7.01      16.5    
 4 3226H5 Type A 2021-04-05 10:10:09 10.5           1 2021-04-01 00:00:00      9.55      20.1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the prior 2 months + all observations with current month (ie 3 months of observations), you might want something like:

```
library(lubridate); library(slider)
my_data %>%
  group_by(REGION, TYPE) %>%
  mutate(MONTHLY = floor_date(DATE, "month"),
         rolling_mean = slide_index_dbl(RESULT, 
                                        MONTHLY,
                                        mean,
                                        .before = months(2)),
         rolling_count = slide_index_dbl(RESULT, # to show how many rows included
                                        MONTHLY,
                                        ~sum(!is.na(.x)),
                                        .before = months(2)))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 50 × 7
# Groups:   REGION, TYPE [3]
   REGION TYPE   DATE                RESULT MONTHLY             rolling_mean rolling_count
   <chr>  <chr>  <dttm>               <dbl> <dttm>                     <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 3226H5 Type A 2021-01-04 10:03:00   0.71 2021-01-01 00:00:00         1.09             4
 2 3226H5 Type A 2021-01-04 10:14:39   1.47 2021-01-01 00:00:00         1.09             4
 3 3226H5 Type A 2021-01-04 10:21:23   1.28 2021-01-01 00:00:00         1.09             4
 4 3226H5 Type A 2021-01-07 09:20:00   0.9  2021-01-01 00:00:00         1.09             4
 5 3226H5 Type A 2021-02-01 10:00:00   1.39 2021-02-01 00:00:00         1.14             8
 6 3226H5 Type A 2021-02-01 10:10:00   1.42 2021-02-01 00:00:00         1.14             8
 7 3226H5 Type A 2021-02-01 10:20:00   1.54 2021-02-01 00:00:00         1.14             8
 8 3226H5 Type A 2021-02-04 10:00:00   0.37 2021-02-01 00:00:00         1.14             8
 9 3226H5 Type A 2021-03-01 10:05:00   2.94 2021-03-01 00:00:00         1.4             12
10 3226H5 Type A 2021-03-01 10:20:00   2.25 2021-03-01 00:00:00         1.4             12
# … with 40 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what is wanted is:

- one row of output per region/type/year/month
- cases is to be the number of rows over which rollapplyr is applied

note that the width= argument of `rollapplyr` can be a vector of the widths, i.e. we can use `cases` and that yearmon class internally represents year and month as year + fraction where fraction is 0, 1/12, ..., 11/12 for the 12 months so 2 months ago is 2/12 less than the current yearmon date.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

my_data %>%
  group_by(REGION, TYPE) %>%
  mutate(DATE = as.yearmon(DATE),
    cases = 1:n() - match(DATE - 2/12, DATE, nomatch = 1) + 1, ##
    mean = rollapplyr(RESULT, cases, mean, fill = NA),
    sd = rollapplyr(RESULT, cases, sd, fill = NA)
  ) %>%
  group_by(DATE, .add = TRUE) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-RESULT)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 15 × 6
   REGION TYPE   DATE      cases    mean       sd
   <chr>  <chr>  <yearmon> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 3226H5 Type A Jan 2021      4 1.09     0.347  
 2 3226H5 Type A Feb 2021      8 1.14     0.425  
 3 3226H5 Type A Mar 2021     12 1.4      0.743  
 4 3226H5 Type A Apr 2021     12 2.14     2.73   
 5 3226H5 Type A May 2021     12 7.01    16.5    
 6 3226H5 Type B Jan 2021      4 0.00875  0.00499
 7 3226H5 Type B Feb 2021      8 0.00863  0.00421
 8 3226H5 Type B Mar 2021     12 0.00917  0.00415
 9 3226H5 Type B Apr 2021     12 0.0095   0.00549
10 3226H5 Type B May 2021     12 0.0102   0.00638
11 3285   Type B Jan 2021      2 0.012    0      
12 3285   Type B Feb 2021      4 0.0115   0.001  
13 3285   Type B Mar 2021      6 0.0127   0.00320
14 3285   Type B Apr 2021      6 0.0128   0.00319
15 3285   Type B May 2021      6 0.0142   0.00293
```

Note that an alternative expression for `cases` would be to replace the line marked ## with:

```
cases = 1:n() - findInterval(DATE - 3/12, DATE),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function:

`summary <- function(.my_data) {summarise(my_data, moving_SD = sd(RESULT), moving_avg = mean(RESULT, na.rm = TRUE), num_observations = n())}`

use it in:

````
 group_by(TYPE, REGION) %>%   mutate(MONTHLY = slide_period_dfr(.x=RESULT, .i = DATE, .period = "month",
      .f = summary, .before = 5, .complete = FALSE))```
````